# The char* fn_Substr(char* s, short m, short n) function does not return the correct value

Tags: c++, c++builder, interbase

I am developing a *user defined function* dll **ib_udf64cpp.dll** to my **InterBase 2020** database.

I am using **Embarcadero C++ Builder Alexandria 11.1** to develop and test the functions exported from the **ib_udf64cpp.dll**.

The code of the exported `fn_SubStr(...)` function from the **ib_udf64cpp.dll** is:

```
/*===============================================================
 fn_SubStr(s, m, n) - Returns the substr starting m ending n in s.
================================================================= */
char* EXPORT fn_SubStr(char* s,
                short m, /* starting position */
                short n) /* ending position */
{
    short i = 0;
    short j = 0;
    char buffer = (char *)ib_util_malloc(256);

    if (m > n || m < 1 || n < 1)
        return "Bad parameters: m, n in substring";
    else
        {
            while (*s && i++ < m-1) /* skip */
                s++;

            while (*s && i++ <= n)  /* copy */
                buffer[j++] = *s++;

            buffer[j] = '\0';

            return buffer;
        }
}
```

This function uses the `ib_util_malloc(256)` function from InterBase 2020 API to initialize the `char* buffer` variable.

*UDFs must allocate memory using `ib_util_malloc()` rather than static arrays in order to be thread-safe*

When I debug the code of this function with:
`s = "1234567890";  m = 2; n = 7`.

I get the following value of `buffer = 0x0000000000894690 "234567"`.

The main program `DLLDebugger` used to debug the **ib_udf64cpp.dll** has the following code:
*(Note: InterBase recommends to use the `cdecl` calling convention.)*

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libloaderapi.h>
#include "ufrmDLLDebugger.h"
#include "uIB_UDF64cpp.h"
#pragma comment (lib, "ib_udf64cpp.a")
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
#pragma comment(lib, "ib_udf64cpp")

TfrmDLLDebugger *frmDLLDebugger;

const wchar_t* ib_udf64cpp_dll = L"d:/MyFiles/Database/IB_UDF64C/Cpp/Win64/Debug/ib_udf64cpp.dll";

extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) char*  __cdecl fn_SubStr(char*, short, short);
typedef char   (*SUBSTR)(AnsiString, ShortInt, ShortInt);

SUBSTR      fnc_SubStr;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TfrmDLLDebugger::TfrmDLLDebugger(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TfrmDLLDebugger::btnExecutarUDFClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    int m, n;
    AnsiString astr;

    HINSTANCE dllhandle = LoadLibrary(ib_udf64cpp_dll);

    if (dllhandle == NULL)
    {
        ShowMessage("Error: The library ib_udf64cpp.dll was not loaded!");
    }
    else
    { switch(rdgSelUDF->ItemIndex)
        {
         case -1 : ShowMessage("Select one of the UDFs.");
                             break;

         case  3 : {fnc_SubStr = (SUBSTR)GetProcAddress(dllhandle, "fn_SubStr");
                             if (Trim(edS->Text) == "")
                             {
                                 ShowMessage("The [s:] field is empty");
                                 break;
                             }

                             if (Trim(edM->Text) == "")
                             {
                                 ShowMessage("The [m:] field is empty.");
                                 break;
                             }
                             if (Trim(edN->Text) == "")
                             {
                                 ShowMessage("The [n:] field is empty.");
                                 break;
                             }
                             astr = AnsiString(edTexto->Text);
                             m = StrToInt(edM->Text);
                             n = StrToInt(edN->Text);
                             astr = fnc_SubStr(astr, m, n);
                             lblResult->Caption = astr;
                             break;}
     }
    }
}
```

**The returned value of `fn_Substr()` assigned to `lblResult->Caption` should be "234567" instead of "`".**

**How can I assign the correct returned value of `buffer` from `fn_Substr(s, m, n)` to the `lblResult->Caption`?**

Comment: `char *buffer = (char *)**ib_util_malloc**(256);` -- Do not use `*` to highlight text.  As you can see, that line of code looks confusing with the intermingling of `*` used as a pointer and as a highlighting tool.

Comment: If the issue is with the substring function, why is it necessary to show all of those other functions?  What significance is, for example, showing the lower case and upper case functions?  You should post a [mcve] -- as a matter of fact, why not write a very simple `main` program, and simply call the function in question to test it with hard-coded data?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, thank you for your recommendations. I have edited the post to the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: `astr = fnc_SubStr(astr, m, n);` -- What is the value of `astr` after that function is called?

Comment: You are passing `AnsiString` to a function that expects `char*`. The function ends up working on the in-memory representation of `astr` - that is, on `(char*)&astr` - not on the character sequence the string is managing. Declare `SUBSTR` as taking `char*` and call it as `fnc_SubStr(astr.c_str(), m, n);` Similarly, `SUBSTR` is declared to return `char` (a single character) while the actual exported function returns `char*`. Bottom line - when you do `(SUBSTR)GetProcAddress(dllhandle, "fn_SubStr")` you have to make extra sure that `SUBSTR` actually matches the signature of the exported function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, the value of `astr = ""`. The value of `astr` should be `"234567"`.
Inside the `fnc_SubStr(...)` function the returned value is `0x0000000000894690 "234567"`.

Comment: @IMeMine In addition to what Igor said - `ShortInt` is not `short`, it is `signed char`. `Smallint` is `short`. But **don't change data types**. `fn_SubStr` wants `(char*, short, short)` and returns `char*`, but your `SUBSTR` wants `(AnsiString, ShortInt, ShortInt)` and returns `char`. So *everything* about your `SUBSTR` is incompatible with `fn_SubStr`. Use the same types that `fn_SubStr` actually wants: `typedef char* (*SUBSTR)(char*, short, short);`

Comment: @IMeMine Also, your Form code is leaking the `char*` memory returned by `fn_SubStr()`.  And the input `char*` really should be `const char*` instead. And `fn_SubStr()` is leaking memory if the input values are out of range, and will overflow the `buffer` if `n-m` is more than 255 characters. In fact, your whole implementation of `fn_SubStr` can be greatly simplified, you don't need the `while` loops at all (certainly not the 1st one, at least. It can be replaced with simple pointer arithmetic. The 2nd loop can be replaced with `strncpy()` or `memcpy()` instead).

Answer (score -1):

I changed the prototype of the `fn_Substr` function, from `char* fn_SubStr(char* s, short m, short n)` to `char* fn_SubStr(char* s, short* m, short* n)`.

I also changed the code of the `DLLDebugger` program I have used to debug the `ib_udf64cpp.dll` that exports the `fn_SubStr()` function, like so:

```
    const wchar_t* ib_udf64cpp_dll = L"d:/IB_UDF64C/Cpp/Win64/Debug/ib_udf64cpp.dll";

/* Changed code of the DLLDebugger program */

    extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) char*  __cdecl fn_SubStr(char*, short*, short*); 

    typedef char*  (*SUBSTR)(const char*, short*, short*);
    
    SUBSTR      fnc_SubStr;
    
    void __fastcall TfrmDLLDebugger::btnExecuteUDFClick(TObject *Sender)
    {
        int intvalue;

    int* im = new int(0);
    int* in = new int(0);

    short* sm = new short(0);
    short* sn = new short(0);

    const char* cstr;

    HINSTANCE dllhandle = LoadLibrary(ib_udf64cpp_dll);

    if (dllhandle == NULL)
    {
        ShowMessage("Error: The library ib_udf64cpp.dll was not loaded!");
    }
    else
    {  
        switch(rdgSelUDF->ItemIndex)
        {
         case -1 : ShowMessage("Select one of the UDFs.");
                             break;
          
         case  3 : {fnc_SubStr = (SUBSTR)GetProcAddress(dllhandle, "fn_SubStr");
                             str = edS->Text;
                             intvalue = StrToInt(edM->Text);
                             *sm = intvalue;
                             intvalue = StrToInt(edN->Text);
                             *sn = intvalue;
                             cstr = str.c_str();
                             cstr = fnc_SubStr(cstr, sm, sn);
                             lblResult->Caption = cstr;
                             break;}
        }    
    }

  if (im != nullptr)
    delete im;

  if (in != nullptr)
    delete in;

  if (sm != nullptr)
    delete sm;

  if (sn != nullptr)
    delete sn;
}
```

This appears to solve the problem.

Comment: This is, as far as I can tell, not at all what was recommended. Also, please keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**.